# Il sintagma pensato come sinonimo di complemento

Tags: grammar

Salve a tutti, 
sto cercando di capire il concetto di sintagma. Leggendo diverse pagine su internet ho finora capito ciò che ho così riassunto (vedi la foto in allegato).

[image]

La mia domanda a questo punto è: posso pensare al sintagma come a un sinonimo di complemento? 
Entrambi in fondo analizzano le funzioni di un gruppo di parole all'interno della frase e si trovano appunto a un livello intermedio tra parole e frase.

Comment: Scusa, non riesco a leggere agevolmente il tuo manoscritto, ma la risposta alla domanda è sicuramente no. Un complemento ha una funzione logica ben precisa (in “Gigi mangia la mela”, “la mela” è il complemento oggetto e finisce lì), mentre un sintagma è un “mattoncino” composto da una o più parole che può svolgere vari ruoli. “la mela” è un sintagma anche se fa da soggetto, per esempio. E i sintagmi verbali come farebbero a essere complementi, s'è per questo?

Comment: Sì hai ragione per quanto riguarda il verbo. Ero piuttosto confusa soprattutto dopo aver trovato questa definizione di sintagma, che a me pareva uguale a quella di complemento.

Comment: • Ogni frase può essere divisa in gruppi di parole che, insieme, mantengono
un significato e hanno una funzione all’interno della frase: questi
gruppi di significato si chiamano SINTAGMI.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Penso sia una domanda molto interessante, E.V., spero di riuscire a risponderti bene! Premetto che sono partito da Wikipedia, nel costruire questa risposta, quindi troverai la trattazione completa anche lì (che potrebbe però essere eccessivamente articolata).

Partiamo dal quesito specifico: "*sintagma*" **non** è sinonimo di "*complemento*".

Il **[complemento](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_%28linguistica%29)** *è un elemento della frase che ha la funzione di completare, arricchire o specificare il significato del predicato verbale*. E', quindi, un'informazione che fornisci allo scopo di aggiungere contenuto informativo. Ad esempio, prendiamo la frase "Luigi è stato aiutato da Mario". Questa frase utilizza uno dei più noti complementi, ovvero quello *d'agente* ("da Mario"): se non ci fosse, avremmo comunque l'informazione inerente il fatto che Luigi sia stato aiutato; l'aggiunta del complemento, però, aggiunge ulteriore contenuto informativo alla frase: stiamo dicendo anche *chi* lo ha aiutato.

Il [sintagma](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintagma), invece, è una singola unità della struttura complessiva della frase. In parole povere, qualunque frase può essere "scomposta" in sintagmi.
I criteri che hai riassunto sono corretti, e sono quelli proposti da Salvi & Vanelli, come "trucchi" per identificarli. Per chi non dovesse riuscire a leggere bene i tuoi appunti, li trova [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tipi-di-sintagma_%28Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano%29/).

Prendendo un esempio del link di Wikipedia, e tornando al tuo quesito originale, considera questa frase (con la divisione esplicita in sintagmi):

Mario gioca in camera sua.

a[ b[Mario]b c[gioca d[in e[camera f[sua]f ]e ]d ]c ]a.

```
a = l'intera frase
b = Mario
c = gioca in camera sua
d = in camera sua
e = camera sua
f = sua
```

Come vedi, "Mario" è il soggetto della frase (e non un complemento!) tuttavia, da solo, costituisce un sintagma: il *sintagma nominale* della frase.
Abbiamo anche "in camera sua", che è sia sintagma che complemento (di luogo).